# Using different name of state variable causes infinite rerender

Tags: reactjs

I'm seeing behavior I don't understand when using state hooks.  I have the following code that is setting up a card game.  I've removed the contents of `loadDeck` and `initializePlayers` as well as the `deal` function which is in an imported js file.

```
export const GameBoard = () => {

    const [players, setPlayers] = useState()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [playersLoaded, setPlayersLoaded] = useState(false)

    let finalizedPlayers = []
    let deckVar = []    
    let playersVar = [] 

    setGame()

    async function setGame() {
        if (!playersLoaded) {
            playersVar = await initializePlayers()
            deckVar = await loadDeck(4)
            finalizedPlayers = await deal(playersVar, deckVar)
            console.log(['setGame - playersVar', playersVar])
            //setPlayers(finalizedPlayers)
            //setLoading(false)
            setPlayersLoaded(true)
        }
    }

    function initializePlayers() {...}
    function loadDeck(playerCount) {...}

    return (
        <div>hi</div>
    )
}
```

When I run it as shown, setGame is called once.  The logging shows the playersVar looks as I'd expect.

When I uncomment the `setPlayers(finalizedPlayers)` line, the log shows setGame is called twice.  This is a little surprising to me since there are no `useEffect`s or any other code responding to/caring about the state variable, `players`.  **Question 1: Why does setting this state variable trigger a re-render?**  It is more complex (an array of elements that contain arrays and other values).  Is it related to players source being based on async function results?

Where it gets particularly strange (to me) is that if I comment out the `setPlayersLoaded(true)` 
 and uncomment `setLoading(false)`, it falls into an infinite re-rendering loop.  **Question 2:  Why???**  I've commented out all use of `loading`, so I believe it is essentially the same as `playersLoaded` where a bool is being toggled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `setPlayer` inside `useEffect` to call when `playersLoaded` changes (also runs on first render).

```js
export const GameBoard = () => {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState()
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [playersLoaded, setPlayersLoaded] = useState(false)

  let finalizedPlayers = []
  let deckVar = []    
  let playersVar = [] 

  async function setGame() {
    if (!playersLoaded) {
      playersVar = await initializePlayers()
      deckVar = await loadDeck(4)
      finalizedPlayers = await deal(playersVar, deckVar)
      console.log(['setGame - playersVar', playersVar])
      //setPlayers(finalizedPlayers)
      //setLoading(false)
      setPlayersLoaded(true)
    }
  }

  useEffect(function() {
    setGame();
  }, [playersLoaded]);

  function initializePlayers() {...}
  function loadDeck(playerCount) {...}

  return (
    <div>hi</div>
  )
}
```

Don't forget to `import { useEffect } from 'react'`.

Comment: In many hacks, I thought I had tried that, but it seems I was wrong!  Any theories on why setLoading caused infinite re-renders while setPlayersLoading did not?

Comment: when you `setPlayersLoading(true)` it sets playersLoaded to true and `if (!playersLoaded) {` body is not running because `!playersLoaded != true`.  I'm sorry I couldn't explain well due to my english knowledge :(